"Cannot index into a null array" : Data.SqlClient error with Powershell
I am creating a PowerShell script that bulk inserts a file from a directory into a SQL Server table. The script is as follows:
$server = "MYSERVER"
$database = "ERDS_LANDING"
$table = "load.load_FRONTARENA_Cashflow"
$query = @"
  DECLARE @loadedRowCount INT;
        
        BULK INSERT  
        $table
        FROM 
           '\\My Directory\Bond_1_1_20240913_1374d9f6-bbbd-4224-a570-bfa96d351f19.CSV'
       WITH 
       ( 
       DATAFILETYPE='char' 
    , CODEPAGE='raw' 
    , FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' 
    , FIRSTROW = 2 
    , FORMATFILE='\\My Directory\load_FRONTARENA_Cashflow.fmt'
      ) 
      select @@ROWCOUNT AS Row_Count;
"@

# Create a new SQL connection
$connectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;Integrated Security=True;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
#$connection.open

# Create the SQL command
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

# Create the DataAdapter
$dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$dataAdapter.SelectCommand = $command


$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
$rowCount = $dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Row_Count"]
"Row count: $rowCount"
$connection.Close()

In my query I use @@rowcount after the bulk insert statement to capture the number of rows inserted into the destination table. When I try and access the row count I get the following error:
1
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:40 char:1
+ $rowCount = $dataSet.Tables[1].Rows[0]["Row_Count"]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
 
Row count: 6246


I have the following questions:

Why do I get the Null array error?
Although the script fails it does return the expected row count and the number 1. What does the number 1 signify in this context?
How do I assign ONLY the row count to a variable which I can use for a condition later on in the script?


[so] questions should ask a single focused question, however, in some cases closely related questions are allowed. The questions here, however, though about the same script, aren't related to the same problems, so this post is likely to be closed as lacking focus. I suggest focusing on one problem and providing an [mre] (which we don't have at the moment) so that that question can be answered. If you then have more questions, write a specific question for that problem.

BULK INSERT doesn't return any results, so Tables is always empty.  What are you trying to do? Why not use bcp from the command line instead of a BULK INSERT command? They do the same job.

Does the behaviour change if you SET NOCOUNT ON;?

You can load and bulk import data into SQL Server using Powershell commands too. For starters, ADO.NET's SqlBulkCopy will use the same mechanism as BULK INSERT and BCP to bulk import data from a client-side DataTable or DataReader into the server. If you use the the SqlServer module with Install-Module SqlServer you can use Import-Csv and then Write-SqlTableData eg: Import-Csv -Path $csvPath -Delimiter $csvDelimiter | Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance $serverName -DatabaseName $databaseName -SchemaName $tableSchema -TableName $tableName -Force

Finally, if the query returns a single result use ExecuteScalar to return the first value of the first result row.

Not to mention DbaTools Import-DbaCsv command, @PanagiotisKanavos .

@Panagiotis Kanavos I am  bulk inserting the csv data into a table, checking the number of rows inserted and comparing it later to the number of rows in the csv. If there is a difference the process is stoped

@ThomA SET NOCOUNT ON does not change the behaviour

What you try won't do that. Besides, the only reason you'd get an unexpected result is if the process crashed completely. It's far easier to just get the error from Write-SqlTableData than try to infer there was an error from the count. Even with the current code, using ExecuteNonQuery would return an exception if the import failed. If you use Import-Csv you can count the number of rows before you start importing the data

Don't you get an error before the array error? Something like file not exists? Can you paste the whole stacktrace

@PanagiotisKanavos I will try your suggestions and let you know. Thanks

Aside... the error message doesn't exactly tally with the code, $rowCount = $dataSet.Tables[1].Rows[0]["Row_Count"] as opposed to the code accessing Tables[0]. Are you executing a different version of the PowerShell script by chance?

The first 1 on the console is probably the number of rows added to the DataSet by SqlDataAdapter.Fill(), which you could squelch with $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null.

@AlwaysLearning This did the trick. Thank you very much!!

@AlwaysLearning The PowerShell script has to eventually be executed by WhereScapeRed. However I always test my scripts first in a PowerShell console so it is likely that I might have mixed up screens.
